# SnappyData SQL if else

Tags: sql, snappydata

I have two tables that I need to join

```
table_A(ID, val), table_B(ID, val)
```

to get a new table

```
RESULT(ID, value)
```

Where the value should be populated like this

Case1: if there is a ID that exists in in both table_A and table_B, value should be 1,

Case2: if the ID only exists in table_A and does not exists in table_B, value should be 0.

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT AS
SELECT A.ID, {TODO}
FROM table_A A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B B 
      On A.ID = B.ID
```

I know I can use left outer join like above, and replace {TODO} with
 COALESCE(B.ID, 0) to handle the second case, but how to include case 1 as well in just one SQL sentence in SnappyData SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If id exist in A and not exist in B during a left outer join, B's Id will be null

```
SELECT A.ID, (CASE WHEN B.ID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) As value
  FROM TableA A left outer join 
       TableB B
 ON A.ID = B.ID
```